# Yii2 | advanced project template at shared hosting wrong redirect route

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a shared host and I uploaded my project on the host based on [this topic](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/topic-shared-hosting) and for enabling `PrettyURL` I added `.htaccess` to root folder (`www`) and also added `urlManager` to `common/config/main.php`.

my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

my `common/config/main.php`:

```php
<?php
return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],

        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
    ],
];
```

but when I not logged in and I going to `site.com/admin` I redirect to `site.com/admin/site/login` and get `404 ERROR`.

but when I disable `PrettyUrl` I redirect to `site.com/admin/index.php?r=site%2Flogin` and its work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the same `.htaccess` file inside your `admin/` folder also as you added in root folder.